# Spring Batch csv FIle to Mongo DB "Error creating bean mongoTemplate"

Tags: mongodb, csv, spring-boot, spring-batch

Spring Batch CSV to MongoDB

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'batchConfig': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'mongoTemplate'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoTemplate'
>   parameter 0; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'mongoDbFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory]: Factory
>   method 'mongoDbFactory' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory.(Lcom/mongodb/MongoClient;Ljava/lang/String;)V

### Pom.xml

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.ge</groupId>
    <artifactId>springbatch-csv-postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>SpringBatchCSVPostgreSQL</name>
    <description>Project for Spring Batch CSV Data to postgresql</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
      </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver ->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Show your configuration. Just providing the stack trace wouldn't help

Comment: spring.data.mongodb.host=127.0.0.1
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=test
server.port=8081

Comment: Can you add your  Pom.xml to the post ?

Comment: pom.xml is available now @Veeram